# How to satisfy no-margin inside a NSTableCellView using Cocoa Auto Layout

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have created a custom NSTableCellView with some subviews aligned using Cocoa Auto Layout. Nothing bad at all except when I placed the NSOutlineView (using the custom NSTableCellView) inside a NSSplitView.

The problem occurs when I have tried to collapse the splitView where the custom NSTableCellView fails all the time to satisfy the horizontal constraint, in details the margin specified by the "-" character between _imageView and _textField does not to be zero length.

The horizontal constraint looks like:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_imageView]-[_textField]|"
                                                                 options:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView, _textField)]];
```

Does someone have an idea how to make the margin between the _imageView and _textField flexible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `H:|[_imageView]-(<=8)-[_textField]|` to make the margin flexible.
Or you could keep a hold of the constraints and remove them when you need to collapse the split view

Comment: Maybe the better way is to hold the constraint and in the case remove it. Thank you for the answer, the syntax to manage the flexibility of the default Cocoa space is new to me but it's so useful. :)